# Is there a mark down to hide a block of contents in our posts?

Tags: support, markdown

In programming language we have a keyword to make a comment in the code.
This comment will not be compiled or rendered.

If this capability is also available here, we can add comments to our posts but they will not be shown on the rendered HTML. Is there a mark down to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HTML comments `<!--   ....    -->`. (See the [source code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/4932c09a-9ccc-40d0-ac31-e8de503e9e04/view-source) of this answer for an example). Please do not abuse this feature. Temporary disabling some parts of a post should be OK.

Comment: This comment may go further than the original question. I feel weird concerning this site where mark down tags are mixed up with  plain HTML tags. It seems that the original objective of inventing mark down tags, i.e., making more fluid transition between contents and markups,  has been broken here. Thank you.

Comment: @xport: They simply support mark down *and* a limited set of HTML tags, so people can choice which one they are using. That mark down doesn't have a comment feature can't be really blamed on stackexchange. You normally don't need it. It's not a programming language.

Comment: @xport: in what scenarios do you envision using this? HTML is allowed in Markdown to handle edge-cases where there's no Markdown syntax defined - I would think *commenting* is very much an edge-case...?